# run multiple instances of python script simultaneously

Tags: python, concurrency, python-multithreading, fork

I am trying to create 86 instances of task.py to run simultaneously.

```
import sys
import subprocess

for file in range(86):
    subprocess.call([sys.executable,'task.py',str(file)+'in.csv',str(filen)+'out.csv'])
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @Alex the problem was "subprocess.call waits for command to complete. Use subprocess.Popen instead:"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) waits for command to complete. Use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) instead:

```
import sys
import subprocess

procs = []
for i in range(86):
    proc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'task.py', '{}in.csv'.format(i), '{}out.csv'.format(i)])
    procs.append(proc)

for proc in procs:
    proc.wait()
```

Comment: Is this solution a "multithread" solution? Or actually it launches multiple instance of python?

Comment: @Lisa, As the name of the module suggest, it launches multiple instances (sub"process"). (OP's original code also launches multiple instances)

Comment: I was just searching for something like this for so much time. Thank you

Comment: I can't get it to work when looping and appending:
`out =subprocess.Popen("hugo server -D", stdout = subprocess.PIPE)`
 `outputs.append(out)`

And then iterating through outputs and calling `output.wait()`.

It opens up the first program, but then doesn't open up the next one unless I close the first program.

Comment: @MasayoMusic, Replace `"hugo server -D"` -> `['hugo', 'server', '-D']`. If that does not work, please post a separate question so that others can answer you.

Comment: @falsetru  I did create one yesterday (just updated), but I couldn't get an answer so I have been hunting around:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57466534/cant-launch-multiple-local-servers-using-subprocess-in-python`

Comment: @falsetru What is the purpose of the `sys.executable` in the Popen command...I looked into the official docs but could not find them using it.

Comment: @PeDro, [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) is an absolute path to the executable of current python process. It was coming from OP's code. My assumption is that OP wanted to use the same python executable for the sub-process.