# Restrict number of subprocess.Popen

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

Following from [run multiple instances of python script simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156467/run-multiple-instances-of-python-script-simultaneously) I can now write a python program to run multiple instances.

```
import sys
import subprocess

for i in range(1000):
  subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'task.py', '{}in.csv'.format(i), '{}out.csv'.format(i)])
```

This starts 1000 subprocess simultaneously. If the command that each subprocess is runs is computationally resource intensive, this can result in load on the machine (may even crash).

Is there a way where I can restrict the number of subprocess to be run at a time? For example something like this:

```
if (#subprocess_currently_running = 10) {
   wait(); // Or sleep 
}
```

That is just allow 10 subprocess to run at a time. In case one out of ten finishes start a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Counting Semaphore* is an old-good mechanism which can be used to control/manage the maximum number of concurrently running threads/processes.

But as each `subprocess.Popen` object (implying process) needs to be [waited](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) for termination, the official doc tells us about the important downside of `subprocess.Popen.wait()`(for this case of multiple concurrent sub-processes):

> **Note:** The function is implemented using a busy loop (non-blocking call and short sleeps). Use the `asyncio` module for an asynchronous
>   wait: see `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec`.

Thus, it's preferable for us to switch to:

- [asyncio.create_subprocess_exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.create_subprocess_exec)
- [asyncio.Semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore)

---

How it can be implemented:

```
import asyncio
import sys

MAX_PROCESSES = 10


async def process_csv(i, sem):
    async with sem:  # controls/allows running 10 concurrent subprocesses at a time
        proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(sys.executable, 'task.py',
                                                    f'{i}in.csv', f'{i}out.csv')
        await proc.wait()


async def main():
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(MAX_PROCESSES)
    await asyncio.gather(*[process_csv(i, sem) for i in range(1000)])


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly. Really helpful was the implementation you presented. Cheers. Although restricting memory is still an issue; an orthogonal one.